# Implementations of an Adder in VHDL comparison

Tags: vhdl

Can someone explain me why this implementation works

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Adder is
    port(A: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    B: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    SUM: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CO: out std_logic);
end;

architecture DescriptionAdders of Adder is

signal temp:  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal temp1: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal temp2: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin

temp1 <= '0' & A;
temp2 <= '0' & B;
temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp1) + unsigned(temp2));

SUM <= temp(3 downto 0);
CO <= temp(4);

end;
```

while this doesn't (the SUM is XX when it starts running, then it is always one step behind the real result, but the temps update well).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Adder is
    port(A: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    B: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    SUM: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CO: out std_logic);
end;

architecture DescriptionAdders of Adder is

signal temp:  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal temp1: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal temp2: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin

process(A, B) is
begin
    temp1 <= '0' & A;
    temp2 <= '0' & B;
    temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp1) + unsigned(temp2));
end process;

SUM <= temp(3 downto 0);
CO <= temp(4);

end;
```

Sorry if the question is too easy, I'm a begginer.

Comment: Move the assignment to temp outside the process (another process or make all three assignments concurrent, which elaborates to three processes).  Without temp1 and temp2 in a sensitivity list temp will not be assigned until the next event on A or B.

Comment: Jim Lewis might have  popped in and remarked that revision -2008 to the VHDL standard includes the reserved word **all** as a single sensitivity list element and would construct a sensitivity list for an implied wait statement according to the rules found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement and 10.2 Wait statement. (Here any signal expression on the right hand side of all the assignment statements in the process - A, B, temp1, and term2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be based about a common misconception of how VHDL simulation works.

```
process(A, B)
```

means the process will be triggered at an event of `A` or `B`. What happens in the process are assignments to additional objects

```
temp1 <= '0' & A;
temp2 <= '0' & B;
temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp1) + unsigned(temp2));
```

This means three events will be **scheduled**, one to each of `temp1`, `temp2` and `temp`. But the way VHDL works, the actual assignments *will not occur until the **next delta cycle***. Which occurs *after* the process is evaluated. So even though the lines for assignment to `temp1` and `temp2` are located before the assignemnt to `temp`, *their values have not been changed yet*.

Considering values of `temp1` and `temp2` change after the process is finished, the assignment to `temp` is missed. *Unless* you re-enter the process, by adding the objects to the sensitivity list. E.g.

```
process(A, B, temp1, temp2) is
begin
    temp1 <= '0' & A;
    temp2 <= '0' & B;
    temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp1) + unsigned(temp2));
end process;
```

An alternative solution would be to use variables, which can change inside of the process. But please note that variables can cause difficulties in logic synthesis if not properly used. This example will work:

```
process(A, B) is
    variable temp1, temp2 : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin
    temp1 := '0' & A;
    temp2 := '0' & B;
    temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp1) + unsigned(temp2));
end process;
```

But the question is: why do you need `temp1` and `temp2` *at all*. Just write

```
process(A, B) is
begin
    temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & A) + unsigned('0' & B));
end process;
```

Or a bit more flexible

```
process(A, B) is
begin
    temp <= std_logic_vector(
        resize(unsigned(A), temp'length) +
        resize(unsigned(B), temp'length));
end process;
```

Or even using the `integer` type (limited to 32 bits!)

```
process(A, B) is
begin
    temp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(
        to_integer(unsigned(A)) + to_integer(unsigned(B))
        , temp'length));
end process;
```

Comment: Or use the type system instead of fighting it; declare A,B and Temp of type unsigned, then `temp <= ('0' & A) + ('0' & B);`

Comment: Or even better use -2008 and IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned which treats std_logic_vector as unsigned.